# Facebook oauth callback is not working as expected?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, passport.js, ejs

I am building a simple node app(express+mongoose) where am using facebook login as user authentication.Here the user details gets stored in the mongodb but the facebook callback is not working properly am not able to redirect to my user page after successful login. I am getting 500 internal server error.

Passport.js

```
require('dotenv').config()
const facebookStrategy = require('passport-facebook').Strategy
const User = require('./model/user.mongo')

module.exports = function(passport){
passport.use(new facebookStrategy({
clientID        : process.env.client_id,
clientSecret    : process.env.client_secret,
callbackURL     : "http://localhost:8000/auth/facebook/callback"

},
async function(token, refreshToken, profile, done) {
try{
   const user = await User.findOne({'username': profile.displayName})
   if(user)
   {
    console.log('user found')
    //console.log(user)
    return done(null,user)
   }
   else
   {
      User.create({
        username: profile.displayName
      })
      return done(null,user)
   }
}
catch(err)
{
    console.log(err)
}
console.log(profile)
}))

passport.serializeUser((user,done)=>{
done(user.id,null)
})

passport.deserializeUser(async(id, done)=>{
try
{
    const user = await User.findById(id)
    done(err, user);
}
catch(err)
{
    console.log(err)
}
})}
```

auth.js

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
const authroute = express.Router()
const passport = require('passport')

authroute.get('/',(req,res)=>{
res.render('auth')
})

authroute.get('/profile',isLoggedIn,(req,res)=>{
res.render('profile',{user:req.user})
})

function isLoggedIn(req,res,next)
{
if(req.isAuthenticated())
{
    return next()
}
return res.redirect('/auth')
}

authroute.get('/facebook',passport.authenticate('facebook',{
scope: [,'public_profile','email']
}))

authroute.get('/facebook/callback',passport.authenticate('facebook',
{ failureRedirect:       '/login', failureMessage: true }),
function(req, res) {
res.redirect('/user');
})

authroute.get('/logout',(req,res)=>{
req.logout()
res.redirect('/auth')
})

module.exports = {authroute}
```

index.js

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
app.use(express.json())
require('dotenv').config()
const path = require('path')
const http = require('http')
const helmet = require('helmet')
app.use(helmet())
const morgan = require('morgan')
app.use(morgan('common'))
const mongoose = require('mongoose')
const server = http.createServer(app)
const mongo_url = process.env.mongodb_url
const bodyParser = require('body-parser')
const {authroute} = require('./controller/auth')
const {userroute} = require('./controller/user')
const passport = require('passport')
const session = require('express-session')
const cookieParser = require('cookie-parser')
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}))
app.set('views',path.join(__dirname,'views'))
app.set('view engine','ejs')

require('./passport')(passport)
app.use(session({
secret: "Harvey_Specter",
resave: false,
saveUninitialized: true,
}))
app.use(passport.initialize())
app.use(passport.session())
app.use(cookieParser())

app.use('/auth',authroute)
app.use('/user',userroute)
server.listen(8000,async(req,res)=>{
await mongoose.connect(mongo_url,{
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useUnifiedTopology: true
}).then(()=>{
    console.log('mongodb connected')
}).catch(err=>console.log(err))
console.log('server is connected')
})
```

Comment: did you ever figure out how to solve this?